# How to measure (content) length of right padded Tensor in Tensorflow 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.x

I've got some sequences of varying length (auch as textual data encoded into numerical data). To fit them into a tensor, they are right-padded to a fixed width using zeros. For example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([[12, 31,  7,  5,  0,  0],
                 [ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
                 [ 44, 9, 11, 21, 20, 22],
                 [  0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Now my question is: **how can I measure the (content) lengths of these padded sequences?**

The output which I would expected from the sample above would be:

```py
x_len = tf.constant([4, 2, 6, 0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to count the number of zeros and subtract it from the width of the tensor, but Tensorflow already has a function for counting non-zero values anyhow: [`tf.math.count_nonzero`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/count_nonzero).

Thus the solution is as simple as the following one liner:

```
x_len = tf.math.count_nonzero(x, axis=1)
```